# GAE - download sample of entities

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

My production app has 23GB of entities in it. I want to download only a handful of these to my dev app to debug.

I have read through https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata. It explains how to download and upload all data, but not just a sample of the data. What I am looking for is a 'number of entity instances to download' config option, but I cannot see it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the bulk download does many small batches of entities; you could just stop it part-way through the process.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is only a handful of entities and you know which ones or have the query for it, you might write a quick web handler to query the data, and stream the bytes back to function as a simple file download.

In the medium to long term, this might end up as a useful utility to invoke whenever you need the data for debugging.